# How to create the OPTIONAL date filed with validation unobtrusive file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create the validation for my STRING types and try to attach the unobstrusive js file on it but still without success.

Here is the code:

```
<input class="valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field @(Model.Attributes[i].AttributeDefinition.Name) must be a date." name="Attributes[@(i)].Value" type="text" value="@Model.Attributes[i].Value">

<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Attributes[@(i)].Value" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

It works perfectly and validates the dates but it doesn't allow me to put empty values. Please help.

And in fact why does data-val-date prevent saving optional values?

Here is my classes:

```
public class AttributeViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
}

public class StudentViewModel : CurrentInfoViewModel
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public List<AttributeViewModel> Attributes { get; set; }

    public long? ImageId { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a View Model for the class that contains this property?

Comment: yes of course, I have it. In my model I have: public List<AttributeViewModel> Attributes { get; set; }

Comment: AttributeViewModel class has this property: public string Value { get; set; }

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. Can you post your View Model code?

Comment: Is your object a DateTime or a DateTime?, the ? is part of the type.  It allows your date time to be nullable.

Comment: @Vulcronos It appears that he's got it defined as a `string`, per his comment above.

Comment: I sure hope you're not defining dates as `string`.

Comment: yes. It should be string because in my collection I can have several types date, string, int etc..

Comment: I just updated the question and my classes

Comment: Is it only 1 way to build the custom validators?

Comment: How are you doing your validations?

Comment: Sorry guys! It works correctly. Just someone overrided the validator! $.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element). I removed it and now it works! Thank you very much for your help and sorry for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works correctly. Just someone overrided the validator! $.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element). I removed it and now it works! Thank you very much for your help and sorry for the question